# Is it possible to authenticate a user using google identity without provider's sign in page

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, google-oauth, google-signin

## Background

I have a web application `"APP1"` (front-end: Vue.js & Back end:Azure function) deployed in azure app service. I have implemented client directed sign in (easy auth using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization)), after that I can authenticate user using provider's sign in page [both AAD & google].

## Target

I have another web application `"APP2"` deployed in on-primes server. I want to redirect to `APP1` from `"APP2"` and automatically sign in `without provider's sign in page`. I will read credentials from environment variable.

**Tried solutions**

- I have found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473089/programmatically-login-to-site-using-google-oauth2), `however I am unable to use the solution because the DB between AAP1 and AAP2 can't be shared`
- I have also checked the [google identity providers documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/authentication), however I am unable to find how to programmatically sign in without provider's sign in page

Question

1. Is it possible to programmatically sign in to google identity to get token without provider's sign in page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of google identity is to prove the identity of the person behind the machine.

`OpenID Connect` is an open standard that companies use to authenticate (signin) users. [IdP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider)s use this so that users can sign in to the IdP, and then access other websites and apps without having to log in or share their sign-in information. (id_token)

`OAuth 2.0`. This standard provides secure delegated access. This means an application created by a developer, can take actions or access resources from a server on behalf of the user, without them having to share their credentials (login and password). It does this by allowing the identity provider (IdP) to issue tokens to third-party applications with the user’s approval.  (access_token, refresh_token)

Comment: Thank you for the response, DalmTo. After a thorough research, I believe programmatically signing in to identity provider might be a possible. Hence, I am not able to achieve the target using easy auth :(.